# How to figure out proper min-width and max-width values for responsive CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, breakpoints

I'm just now diving into responsive CSS and design, and I'm wondering how I'm supposed to figure out various device widths out. I don't want to spend all day testing every single mobile device possible, I just want to get the responsive layout enough to where it works.

I saw some sites using `@media only screen and (max-device-width: xx)` but it seems that limits it to very specific resolutions, not actual browser window sizes.

Any advice at all would be great. I'm not new to web development or CSS, but totally new to responsive design.

Comment: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/ and http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would seem that you're trying to figure out where and when to apply your **breakpoints**.

Rather than testing resolution on a bunch of devices why not build a responsive design that is acceptable at **every** resolution? There are no magic breakpoints that fix  responsive websites for every device because every responsive website is going to differ depending on layout, content, etc. and there are tons of different devices with varying resolutions.

You might be thinking, "*what the hell, I am not going to go pixel by pixel and check my website,*" but that's not really what I mean.

## Finding your website's breakpoints:

1. Jump into a browser, navigate to your website, and open the console
2. Resize the viewport to a very low resolution. 320px is a good starting point.
   (**Note:** To get the size of the viewport type window.innerWidth in console. See **Resources** for more ways to enhance debugging your design)
3. Analyze your layout. How does it look at this resolution? If you need to change the layout at this resolution then its time to add a breakpoint!
4. Slowly stretch the browser window until something breaks or looks horrible. At this point you'll need to insert another breakpoint.
5. Repeat step 4 to your heart's content

Keep in mind:

> The point of responsive design isn't to make your site look good on all devices, its to make your content look good *anywhere* - Sam Richards

### Resources:

- [Responsive Web Design - Programming with Anthony](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BVmrSG93XE)
- [Responsive Typography](http://ia.net/blog/responsive-typography-the-basics/)
- [Logical Breakpoints For Your Responsive Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/01/logical-breakpoints-responsive-design/)
- As mentioned in the above video, [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is an awesome JS library that helps in detecting device-specific features
- [Responsive Design View Feature in Firefox 15+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View)
- [Responsive Design View Tutorial for Chrome](http://blog.divshot.com/post/29829585371/chrome-developer-tools-responsive-design)

Comment: The past few versions of Firefox have included a nice Responsive Design View in `Tools>Web Developer` that has a list of presets for various device resolutions. The keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+M`.

Comment: Great answer! I found a Responsive Inspector for Chrome, but unfortunately it has some issues and doesn't properly detect breakpoints. I might just find a simple browser window extension to easily show the current browser width.

Comment: you can always use console if you're in chrome: **Select View > Developer > JavaScript Console.** I also added a tutorial in my answer on how to use the developer tools in chrome for a better responsive debugging experience :]