# How to change size of icon (picture) based on screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, screen-size, glyphicons

Currently, I have a glyphicon set to the font-size 300. However, when displayed on an extra-small screen (phone), I want it to appear at font-size 200. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use [breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842682/how-to-figure-out-proper-min-width-and-max-width-values-for-responsive-css/16843647#16843647). Bootstrap makes it easy to use [their predefined breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) with LESS.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

For a phone, you'd do something like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .glyphicon {
        font-size: 200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: With bootstrap, a minimum breakpoint is pointless if you're using the predefined breakpoints. (ie `@screen-xs-max`). +1 for the right idea, though.

Comment: I put that into my CSS, but when I readjusted my screen (down to that size), it didn't change the size of the glyphicon.

Comment: That's because the queries focus on min and max `device-width`.  Changing browser viewport does not change device parameters.  Modify the queries to `@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px)` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Viewport units are also excellent to implement responsive layouts that are a bit more continuous.  That is, the screen dimension affects the size of text/image/etc. much more precisely.  For my site I used viewport units and `aspect-ratio` query to adjust the elements sizes.  Here's a simple fiddle that uses `vh` units: http://jsfiddle.net/LKwfs/.  To see the effect, change the height of the viewport.

HTML:

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>
```

Styles:

```
h1 {
    font: bold 5vh/2 Sans-Serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

There is a shim for older browsers and it works pretty well: http://html5polyfill.com/.