# Twitter Bootstrap condense table does not work for appended rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following table:

`<table class="table table-condensed">`

Rows added at the same time when the table is instantiated are rendered properly. However, when a row is later appended dynamically with javascript, it does not follow condensed table layout and takes too much space.

How can I assure that dynamically appended rows follow `table-condensed` formatting as well?

EDIT:
Obviously it was caused, because of the fact that the first element in the table contained shorter cell values than appended rows. As result subsequent, dynamically appended rows inherited columns width.

Here is how it looks like:
[image]

Two first rows have been present in the table from the beginning and the subsequent rows were appended dynamically.

Comment: Hello KoleS,

can you show me as picture ?

Comment: They are condensed, they just have more content so some of the columns are line breaking which causes them to look bigger than the other rows.

Comment: Is there an actual question after the edit? This question is unlikely to be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: @CarrieKendall I think you're correct, because when I populated the two first rows with data from the last row, all rows were rendered properly (condensed). But, I wonder about one thing. When they still were rendered not condensed, I opened google chrome dev tools and suddenly they got fixed - this is they got condensed, even though two first rows contained shorter cell values. What happened there?

Comment: that's because bootstrap is responsive. Check out my answer about responsiveness [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842682/how-to-figure-out-proper-min-width-and-max-width-values-for-responsive-css/16843647#16843647). When you open developer tools, depending on if it comes from the bottom dock or the left dock, it will force a new breakpoint that will often times dramatically alter the layout of your website.

Comment: @CarrieKendall thanks for the explanation. Then there is no question anymore.